# how to set max and and min attributes to input number type without using form tag in ionic3 and angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3

How i can set or apply min and max values between 0 to 1 for an ion-input element using ionic 3 and angular 4

[image: angular ionic3 html sample]

Answer (score 0):

You can use those for static & dynamic values.

Static:

```
<input min="0" max="1" step="0.01">
```

Dynamic:

```
<input [min]="minValue" [max]="maxValue" step="0.01">
```

More details : https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

Comment: here i am not using any form controls in angular and ionic i need without using of form controls